# The method EnterText(WebElement, String) from the type AutomationTest refers to the missing type WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Got above error and not able to run below code
package com.FlightReservation.Pages;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.Pdas.TestAutomation.Pages.Page;
import com.Pdas.TestAutomation.Utilities.Factory;

public class LoginPage 
{

```
Page LoginPage;
public LoginPage()
{

    LoginPage=Factory.FactoryMethod("Desktop","Chrome", this.getClass().getSimpleName());

    try 
    {
        LoginPage.Test.SetupTest();
    } 
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LoginPage.GenerateLocatorStratergyAndLocatorDictionary();

    LoginPage.Test.WaitTillElementFound(LoginPage.Locator_Stratergy_Dict.get("SignInBtn").toString() , LoginPage.Locator_Dict.get("SignInBtn").toString()); 
    LoginPage.GeneratePageRepository();


}

public void EnterUserName(String Uname)
{

    LoginPage.Test.EnterText((WebElement) LoginPage.PageRepository_Dict.get("UserNameField"), Uname);

}


public void EnterPassword(String Pass)
{
    LoginPage.Test.EnterText((WebElement) LoginPage.PageRepository_Dict.get("PasswordField"), Pass);

}

public void ClickSigninButton()
{

    LoginPage.Test.ClickElement((WebElement) LoginPage.PageRepository_Dict.get("SignInBtn"));
}
```

}

Comment: where is EnterText() method ? show us the code inside that.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like the method EnterText is expecting a webelement & a string as parameter. So your code of 
   (WebElement)LoginPage.PageRepository_Dict.get("UserNameField") 
is not actually type casting your dictionary value into WebElement. If the dictionary value is of type String then you need to get the actual webelement using something like : driver.findelement("By","value")

Comment: Added dependencies in POM.xml,So error is solved.But got another error as CSV file not found

Comment: Check the path to this CSV file.